# Подскажите пож-та по серверным настройкам для ТГ бота (WebHook)

Tags: python, nginx, telebot, gunicorn, webhook

Приветствую дорогих IT специалистов. Это моя первая активность на *STACK-O-F*, поэтому прошу не судить строго, если оформил топик неверно или допустил иные ошибки)

К делу. Пытаюсь настроить через **PYTHON`овскую** библиотеку **TELEBOT** (PyTELEGRAMBOTapi) своего первого бота на базе *WebHook* (до этого удалось успешно реализовать несколько ботов на той же либе, но на *polling*).
Искал мануалы по тематике *WebHook* и в ру, и в англ сегментах: как мне увиделось информация достаточно разрозненная или у меня просто "косые руки", поэтому получилась "сборная солянка", которую удается запускать локально, но которая не фунциклирует на удаленной машинке (пользуюсь *vds BEGET*).

Как известно, для успешного взаимодействия с *api ТГ* по *WebHook*, нужно, чтобы на url, куда будут отправляться обновления от сервера ТГ имелся *ssl* сертификат. Причина решения данной проблемы для моего локального варианта  - это применение `ngrok` (он запускается и возникает временный "туннель" с `HTTPS` URL, который ведет в итоге к `LOCKALHOST` домашнего ПК; с этой конструкцией бот стартует и успешно работает по *WebHook*. Локально).

Таким образом, на локалке норм, но как только, что называется, руки дошли до размещения бота на хостинге стали вылезать недопонимания.
Из того, что я нашел для запуска на хостинге - это популярная в таких случаях  связка
`Nginx-Gunicorn` (ну и также `FLASK` и уже отмеченный ранее `TELEBOT`).

За основу моих изысканий для удаленной (работающей на хостинге 24/7) версии бота я взял статью из: https://flask.ivan-shamaev.ru/python-flask-initial-setting-vps-server/  (спасибо автору, искомое для цели его статьи, а именно, сайт, *именно САЙТ*, а не ТГ бот, удалось выполнить и мне; т.е. сайт на `Flask`, руководствуясь мануалом из упомянутой статьи, я сделать смог).
Но тогда, когда я, посчитав, что так тоже заработает и просто поменял код в исполняемом файле (т.е. вместо кода, посредствам которого работал сайт, я вставил код бота) - ,разумеется, чуда не произошло и бот как не ответил сразу после запуска, так он  продолжает не отвечать и сейчас.
Я пробовал "крутить-вертеть" настройки и так, и эдак, но бот не реагирует. Что называется, на лицо, недостаток у меня опыта  ---> отсутствие положительного результата...

**Имею сильные подозрения, что дело в том, что настройки `Nginx` и `Gunicorn`, пригодные для описанного в статье  сайта на `Flask`, который, как я отмечал выше, запустился,  не подходят для того, чтобы "поднять" бота**.

Файл `nginx` имеет следующий вид:

```
server {
    server_name mydomain.ru;
    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/flask123/flaskapp/flaskapp.sock;
    }
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.ru/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.ru/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
server {
    if ($host = mydomain.ru) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.ru;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Файл `wsgi.py`, который расположен в той же директории, что и исполняемый файл бота (имя исполняемого файла бота: `myapp.py`), имеет следующее содержание:

```
from myapp import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Сам исполняемый файл с кодом бота (бот пока, можно сказать, без функционала почти: функционал сейчас - это вторично; первично тут - это разобраться с деплоем) со следующим кодом:

```
from flask import Flask, request
import json
import telebot
from telebot import types

TokenTG = 'MyToken' 
URL = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{TokenTG}/setWebhook?url=https://mydomain.ru'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TokenTG, threaded=False)
bot.remove_webhook()
bot.set_webhook(url=URL)

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/', methods=['POST','GET'])
def ind():
    upDATE=telebot.types.Update.de_json(request.stream.read().decode('utf-8'))
    bot.process_new_updates([upDATE])
    return 'ok', 200


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def abc(message):
    print('ok')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, F'Привет тебе, юзер с id: {message.chat.id}!')

app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Также, как было указано в статье (ссылка на статью, напомню,  выше☝️, по которой получилось сделать сайт на `Flask`, но не получилось с ботом), я сделал т.н. "демон": содержимое файла `SYSTEM-D` таково:

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve flaskapp
After=network.target

[Service]
User=flask123
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/flask123/flaskapp
Environment="PATH=/home/flask123/flaskapp/flaskappenv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/flask123/flaskapp/flaskappenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:flaskapp.sock -m 007 wsgi:app

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Т.к. статья, которой я руководствовался,  поделена на несколько страниц, для простоты поиска, с вашего позволения, я оставлю ссылки на те ее разделы, в которых обсуждалась настройка `Gunicorn` и `SYSTEM-D`:

https://flask.ivan-shamaev.ru/app-flask-service-wsgi-gunicorn-settings/

а также `Nginx`:
https://flask.ivan-shamaev.ru/setup-nginx-and-setting-for-flask-website/

Это на тот случай, если найдется добрый человек, вознамерившийся дать мне наставление и, если для этого ему понадобится ознакомится с источником, откуда я, в свою очередь, взял схему.

Ну и для полноты картины, также оставлю пример кода сайта (повторюсь, именно сайта, а НЕ бота) на `Flask`, который  удалось и удается запускать (схема сайта из статьи):

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
 
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "<center><h1 style='color:blue'>Привет, посетитель)</h1></center>"
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Да, также информирую, что на моем vds уже есть другой, работающий на Джанго сайт, который в недрах своих настроек имеет аналогичную  связку: `Nginx/Gunicorn/SYSTEM-D`.
Насколько последнее важно для разрешения моей текущей незадачи с ботом - не знаю, но мне показалось, что об этом стоит сообщить, т.к. ip упомянутого последним сайта на Джанго, и моего нерешенного проекта (бот ТГ, `WebHook`) - один и тот же, предоставленный vds`ом, отличаются лишь доменные имена.

Буду очень признателен, если кто-то из мастеров веб разработки укажет на мои ошибки и станет причиной долгожданного запуска этого моего пресловутого бота на `WebHook`)
Спасибо за внимание и сильно буду ждать ответов или уточнений) !